# Python: How to account for spaces in caesar's cipher?

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop, replace

```
code = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

no_punct = ""
for char in code:
    if char not in punctuations:
        no_punct = no_punct + char

print(no_punct)

code_cracked = ""

for i in no_punct:
    found = alphabet[alphabet.find(i)]
    new = (alphabet.find(found)+10) % 26
    new_alpha = alphabet[new]
    new_code = i.replace(i, new_alpha)
    code_cracked += new_code

print(code_cracked)

output: heyjtherejthisjisjanjexamplejofjajcaesarjcipherjwerejyoujablejtojdecodejitjijhopejsojsendjmejajmessagejbackjwithjthejsamejoffset
```

Hi everyone, newbie to Python here. I am trying a ceasar's cipher problem in Python. The goal is to use "alphabet" + 10 to solve for "code". For example: the first letter in code is "x" index position of x is 23, the problem requires you to add 10 to the index number and once you reach "z" you go back to "a" to resume counting. So "x" position 23 = "h" position 7.

So far I have been able to solve up to the replacement of the alphabets. I had to google the %26 part as I couldn't figure that out.

I pretty much have the cipher part figured out I just don't know how to deal with the spaces in the sentence. I have tried to add if/elif statements but to no avail so I removed the if statements.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "deal with the spaces"? What do you want to happen to spaces? What happens instead?

Comment: Does it work if you add a space to `punctuations`?

Comment: yazdanimehdi helped solve the problem, thank you both. What I meant with the spaces was in my "output" all the spaces were filled with a "j". What I was trying to achieve was to have regular spaces same as "code". Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can not use some special characters in string without using "\". as you can see in the edited code
2. you can use if statement to check whether the character is space or not and adjust the char that is getting added to the deciphered code

```
code = "xuo jxuhu! jxyi yi qd unqcfbu ev q squiqh syfxuh. muhu oek qrbu je tusetu yj? y xefu ie! iudt cu q cuiiqwu rqsa myjx jxu iqcu evviuj!"
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
punctuations = '''
!()-[]{};:\'\"\\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~
'''

no_punct = ""
for char in code:
    if char not in punctuations:
        no_punct = no_punct + char

print(no_punct)

code_cracked = ""

for i in no_punct:
    if i != ' ':
        found = alphabet[alphabet.find(i)]
        new = (alphabet.find(found)+10) % 26
        new_alpha = alphabet[new]
        new_code = i.replace(i, new_alpha)
        code_cracked += new_code
    else:
        code_cracked += i

print(code_cracked)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .index() instead of .find() and use a try/except statement, .find() returns -1 if the value isn't found but .index() raises a ValueError, so what you should do is wrap it in a try/except method and catch a ValueError exception.

```
foo = 'hello'

print(foo.find('1')) #-1

print(foo.index('1')) #ValueError

try:
    print(foo.index('1'))
except ValueError:
    print(' ')
```